# Why does Apple ship with ruby?

Tags: macos, ruby

Are there system processes that require ruby?

Installing gems using the local ruby will generally ask for permissions and most scripts today ask for a newer version of ruby. Apple has historically removed built in interpreters and stated it will remove php, ruby, and perl. Yet has only removed php. As of macOS 12.4, what still uses ruby?

[Macos Catalina Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes)

Comment: One user of ruby is HomeBrew so removing ruby would cause a lot of complaints. Macports does not rely on Apple supplied tools as far as possible so supplies its own interpreter tclsh so would not be affected if Apple removed tclsh

Comment: ["Please refrain from ... asking how/why Apple does <some thing XYZ>"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @mmmmmm I think Homebrew can bootstrap itself from shell-script without using the macOS system Ruby. They have their own thing called Homebrew Portable Ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why Apple does something is really not possible to answer by any means except by what Apple has officially stated.

The answer lies in the document you have linked - here Apple states that they ship Ruby *"for compatibility with legacy software"*.

So there you have it. Presumably Apple knows that they have customers (probably large ones) that run software that rely on the old Ruby system being there. Removing it would break that software while having only a very marginal benefit of saving some space.

If you as the user want to use a newer version of Ruby, you can just install it.